# Show that $1/2 \cdot (1-2x)^3 \log (1-2x) - (1-x)^3 \log(1-x) + x^3 \log x$ is positive for $x \in (0, 1/2)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Define $f(x) = 1/2 \cdot (1-2x)^3 \log (1-2x) - (1-x)^3 \log(1-x) + x^3 \log x.$

I want to show $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (0, 1/2)$, which I believe is true from plotting, but I'm not sure how to prove it analytically.

One simplifying attempt I've made is using the bounds $1-1/x \le \log(x) \le x - 1$, but unfortunately this yields a lower bound that is negative near $1/2$. Any ideas for proving this function is positive over $(0, 1/2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proof.**

Using the identity for $u > 0$ (easy to prove)
$$\ln u = \int_0^1 \frac{u - 1}{1+(u-1)t}\,\mathrm{d} t,$$
we have
\begin{align*}
 \ln(1 - 2x) &= \int_0^1 \frac{-2x }{1 - 2xt}\,\mathrm{d} t, \\
 \ln(1 - x) &= \int_0^1 \frac{-x}{1 - xt}\,\mathrm{d} t, \\
 \ln x &= \int_0^1 \frac{x - 1}{1+(x-1)t}\,\mathrm{d} t.
\end{align*}

The desired inequality is written as
$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac12 (1 - 2x)^3\cdot \frac{-2x }{1 - 2xt} - (1 - x)^3\cdot \frac{-x}{1 - xt}
+ x^3\cdot \frac{x - 1}{1+(x-1)t}
 \right)\,\mathrm{d}t > 0.$$

It suffices to prove that, for all $t \in [0, 1]$,
$$\frac12 (1 - 2x)^3\cdot \frac{-2x }{1 - 2xt} - (1 - x)^3\cdot \frac{-x}{1 - xt}
+ x^3\cdot \frac{x - 1}{1+(x-1)t} > 0$$
or
$$\frac{x^2(1 - 2x)}{(1 - tx)(1 - 2tx)(tx - t + 1)}[(2x^3 - 4x^2 + x + 1)t^2 - (4 - 4x - x^2)t + 3 - 4x] > 0. $$

It suffices to prove that, for all $t \in [0, 1]$,
$$(2x^3 - 4x^2 + x + 1)t^2 - (4 - 4x - x^2)t + 3 - 4x > 0.$$

Since $4 - 4x - x^2 > 0$, using $t \le \frac{t^2 + 1}{2}$, it suffices to prove that, for all $t \in [0, 1]$,
$$(2x^3 - 4x^2 + x + 1)t^2 - (4 - 4x - x^2)\cdot \frac{t^2 + 1}{2} + 3 - 4x > 0$$
or
$$\frac12 x^2 - 2x + 1 - \left(-2x^3 + \frac72 x^2 - 3x + 1\right)t^2 > 0.$$

Since $-2x^3 + \frac72 x^2 - 3x + 1 > 0$, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac12 x^2 - 2x + 1 - \left(-2x^3 + \frac72 x^2 - 3x + 1\right) > 0$$
or
$$x(1 - x)(1 - 2x) > 0$$
which is true.

We are done.

Comment: for $x\in[0.2,0.5]$ we have : $$h\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(-(1-x)^{3}\log(1-x)\right)}{x^{3}}\leq \frac{f\left(x\right)}{f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}h\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\leq g\left(x\right)=\frac{-\left(1/2\cdot(1-2x)^{3}\log(1-2x)+x^{3}\log x\right)}{x^{3}},f\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)^{2}$$ can we invoke symetry ?

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!

Comment: @KiranTomlinson You are welcome.

Comment: @ErikSatie Do you have a complete proof?

Comment: @RiverLi It goes as follow use VasileCirtoaje left/right convex theorem to show : $$(1-2x)^{3}\log(1-2x)+2x^{3}\log x\ge g\left(\frac{\left(1+2x-2x\right)}{\frac{1}{2}+1+\frac{1}{2}}\right) \ge g\left(x\right)=2(1-x)^{3}\log(1-x),x\in[0.2,0.5]$$ then use the classical bound for log for the remainder interval .Is it right ?

Comment: @ErikSatie I am not following. You should write detailed and complete proof.

Answer (score 0):

Hint using this [LCF theorem](https://journalofinequalitiesandapplications.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/1029-242X-2011-101) we have $x\in(0,1)$:

$$j\left(x\right)+j\left(1-x\right)\geq r\left(x\right)+r\left(1-x\right)\geq 2j\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Where :

$$j\left(x\right)=(1-x)^{3}\ln\left(1-x\right),r\left(x\right)=-(1-x)^{3}x\cdot2\ln\left(2\right)$$

Remains to show :

$$(1-x)^{3}\ln\left(1-x\right)\leq j\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Which is true for $x\in[1/8,1/2]$

Then you can use @ Kiran Tomlinson your own attempt .